# SQL 2008r2 ODBC issue

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a MS 2008R2 SQL server running on a Windows 2008R2 server both virtual servers under Hyper V There are 5 main databases which are all linked to a ERP program.

My users all run Terminal Server (TS) Windows 2008R2 again virtual, we have ODBC connections setup on the TS (under system DSN) to allow users to import data from the SQL database in to MS Excel 2010.

Due to demand on the TS server we are adding a second TS which we are currently testing, now if a user opens a new excel spreadsheet on the new TS and makes an ODBC connection and imports data, he can save it and reopen it on the new TS without a problem.

Now if the user opens an existing Excel spreadsheet on the new TS that was created on the old TS with ODBC links the spreadsheet will not load (the spreadsheet opens but will not load anything).

If the user goes on to the old TS and try to open the new spreadsheet that was created on the new TS with ODBC links this spreadsheet will not open either.

We have found that if we delete the WSID from the ODBC connection string (is that the correct term?) you can open any ODBC linked spreadsheet on any TS but the problems comes when you save and close the spreadsheet because the WSID is re-added to the ODBC connection string.

I believe the WSID is an optional component of the connection string, but can not find anywhere to remove it, is that the best only way to resolve our issue? Both sets of ODBC setting are identical on both the old and new TS

Sorry if I sound vague or used the wrong terminology but this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the issue of creating excel spreadsheet that link to a SQL database and the user doesn't have the proper ODBC connection or it doesn't exist on the client machine.  So I created a method that would automatically create the ODBC connection in the computer/server registry when the Excel file opens.

***NOTE:  This will create the 32bit ODBC connection needed for Microsoft Office 2010 and below database connection.  The newer versions of Microsoft Office use the 64bit ODBC drivers and this method will not work.***

The first method I created was putting the connection information in as static data.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    'This VBA script will automaticall create the ODBC connection for Excel
    'when the user opens the Excel file.  If the ODBC already exists, the
    'valuse will simply be over written with the values you specify below
    'without prompting the user.
    '
    'Please note: The connection password is not permited here and not allowed.
    '             you will need to save it in the Workbook connections if you
    '             do not want to prompt the user everytime for the password.

    odbcName = "SQL-ODBC"
    odbcDesc = "Pentagon2000 Database Connection"
    odbcSrvr = "10.33.0.2"
    odbcUser = "Reports"
      odbcDB = "GDB_01_100"

    Dim WshShell As Object
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   'Write value in the Registry
       WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\", 1, "REG_DWORD"
       WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\Database", odbcDB
       WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\Description", odbcDesc
       WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\Driver", "C:\Windows\system32\SQLSRV32.dll"
       WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\LastUser", odbcUser
       WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\Server", odbcSrvr
       WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources\" & odbcName, "SQL Server"
End Sub
```

I later changed this method because I wanted to have a single place where all my excel reports could read the database connections from, which makes it much simpler to manage from an IT standpoint.  This reads an XML file and loads the values to create the ODBC.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'This VBA script will automaticall create the ODBC connection for Excel
    'when the user opens the Excel file.  If the ODBC already exists, the
    'valuse will simply be over written with the values you specify below
    'without prompting the user.
    '
    'Please note: The connection password is not permited here and not allowed.
    '             you will need to save it in the Workbook connections if you
    '             do not want to prompt the user everytime for the password.


        Dim nodeList As IXMLDOMNodeList
        Set oXMLDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument

        'Locates the setup directory and loads the Configuration.xml
        'This assumes the Excel report is located in the Reports directory
        oXMLDoc.Load (Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Path, "\") - 1) + "\Apps\Setup\Configuration.xml")

        Set nodeList = oXMLDoc.SelectNodes("/data")

        odbcName = "BSC_Reports"
        odbcDesc = "Pentagon2000 Database Connection for BSC Custom Reports"
        odbcSrvr = nodeList(0).SelectNodes("server").Item(0).Text
        odbcUser = nodeList(0).SelectNodes("user").Item(0).Text
          odbcDB = nodeList(0).SelectNodes("pentdb").Item(0).Text

        Dim WshShell As Object
        Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

       'Write value in the Registry
           WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\", 1, "REG_DWORD"
           WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\Database", odbcDB
           WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\Description", odbcDesc
           WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\Driver", "C:\Windows\system32\SQLSRV32.dll"
           WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\LastUser", odbcUser
           WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & odbcName & "\Server", odbcSrvr
           WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources\" & odbcName, "SQL Server"
End Sub
```

Here is the "Configuration.XML" file I read from.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
  <server>WBenhart-M6600\SQL_2008</server>
  <user>Reports</user>
  <pentdb>GDB_01_100</pentdb>
</data>
```

Either method should work on your terminal servers and you won't need to create the ODBC manually.

I hope this helps you.

Wayne Benhart